# Using Haskell Turtle's FilePath with readFile

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I am trying to use Haskell Turtle to do some CSV file processing, but I'm having trouble working with the `Turtle.FilePath` from the option parser.
Here's an exampple:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Lib

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Turtle

data Args = Args Turtle.FilePath
  deriving Show

tfpToStr :: Turtle.FilePath -> String
tfpToStr fpath = show fpath

tfpToPfp :: Turtle.FilePath -> Prelude.FilePath
tfpToPfp fpath = show fpath

parser :: Parser Args
parser = Args <$> (argPath "fname" "The file containing the data")

sname :: String
sname = "salaries.csv"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    Args fname <- options "Salary Printer" parser
    csvData <- BL.readFile (tfpToStr fname)
    -- csvData <- BL.readFile sname
    putStrLn $ show csvData
```

I have a file `salaries.csv` in the same directory.  If I run this, I get back `FilePath "salaries.csv": openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`.  Using `tfpToPfp` yields the same result.  If I comment out the first `readFile` and uncomment the other one that calls `BL.readFile sname` then it works perfectly.   I've also tried `csvData <- BL.readFile $ fromString (tfpToStr fname)`, that also throws an error.

Unfortunately, `BL.readFile` does not take a `Turtle.FilePath` directly; it complains that it didn't get a `Prelude.FilePath`.

So how is one supposed to get a `Turtle.FilePath` into `BL.readFile`?

I'm using stack resolver LTS-9.9 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion can also be performed without directly using `system-filepath`:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

filePathToString :: FilePath -> String
filePathToString = T.unpack . format fp
```

Answer (score 0):

I did happen to find something that worked from [this blog](https://bollu.github.io/teleport/).

```
import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS as Path

filePathToString :: FilePath -> String
filePathToString = Path.encodeString
```

Now I can call

```
csvData <- BL.readFile $ filePathToString fname
```

and it works.  If anyone knows a more idomatic way of doing this, please comment!